# Infinite Ajax Scroll Pager, hide URL page number

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

Is there any way to hide IAS pager URL?

I've remove `#/page/` in [jquery-ias.js](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/blob/master/src/jquery-ias.js), but the URL still showing pages like:

http://foo.com/#2 when go to page 2, http://foo.com/#3 when go to page 3 and so on.

I don't need any pages URL shown when the page really go to next page.

any solutions?

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution for it, I am looking same solution. thanks